# Importing and calling an ES6 module function in a commonJS typescript code

Tags: typescript, async-await, es6-modules, commonjs

In our backend nodeJS (typescript) project we should use the 'parse-domain' package (7.0.1). The problem is that this package is not compatible with commonJS, cannot load with `require`, but for simple `import` function the compiler generates a `require` in the `.js` codes. To build a workaround we wrote a (non async!) wrapper function:

```
public parserDomain(url:string)
{
    let pd = null;
    async () => pd = await import('parse-domain');
    return pd.parseDomain(url);
}
console.log(parserDomain("http://any.company.com"))
```

The problem is that it seems that `pd` is still `null` when the code reaches the `return` operation inside the function.

How could I write a non asnyc function which calls the `parseDomain()` in this case?

Our tsconfig.json is the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [ "esnext", "dom" ],
    "target": "es2015",
    "strict": true,
    "outDir": "./build/src",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": true,    
    "sourceMap" :true,
    "typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@types" ],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "types" : [ "node" ],
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "test/**/*"],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules", "**/*.integration.ts" ]
}
```

Package json line is (nodeJS version is 20.4.0)

```
"parse-domain": "7.0.1",
"typescript": "^5.1.6"
```

Comment: You cannot. `import()` is asynchronous, you must wait for it. There's no way to make an asynchronous function return a value from the future immediately.

Comment: As the [documentation of *parse-domain*](https://github.com/peerigon/parse-domain) states: "*You need to transpile it down to ES5 (e.g. by using Babel) if you need to support older environments.*" Just do that!

Comment: Sorry, I dont really undestand what should I do?! How do you mean that my environment is "old"? The compile target is es2015, which is good enough? Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, if your environment does not support ES modules, then you should transpile the library to commonjs modules. Or just use version 5 which still did support that. https://github.com/peerigon/parse-domain/issues/146

Comment: So the "dynamic import" which is available in all commonJS module - simple won't work in this case? I wonder why?!

Comment: Because it's asynchronous!

Comment: I was able to achieve this in pure javascript, but I don't know how to write it in a typescript environment, because the compiler's generated code still wont work.

Comment: Achieve it how?

Comment: Nope. I cannot write a .js or .ts file which are compiled together with the other files in the project, and do what I want. Pure .js file can do the trick without compiling... :( Cannot tell the typescript compiler "do not touch this .js just use"

Comment: What did you put in that JS file to make it work? And yes, `tsc` does not touch .js files by default!

Comment: This is what works for me (pure .js file, run as "node tryIt.js") `"use strict";

let func = async () => await import("parse-domain").then(p => p.parseDomain("http://my.company.com"));
let result = await func();
console.log(result);
`

Comment: Yes, but that's still asynchronous. The same would work in TypeScript, but you said you needed a synchronous version.

Comment: But when I put this code into a tryIt.js file to my project, and compile it along with the other .ts files - the compiler changes its content.:(

Answer (score 1):

Add `"type":"module"` in the package.json file and use a simple import statement

```
import { parseDomain} from "parse-domain";
```

Comment: Won't work for this package.

Comment: Which package are you using?

Comment: In package.json `"parse-domain": "7.0.1",`, and in `package-lock.json` there are the following section `    "node_modules/parse-domain": {
      "version": "7.0.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/parse-domain/-/parse-domain-7.0.1.tgz",`